# How to use spring tool suite plugin in existing Eclipse Kepler

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I've downloaded the 'spring-tool-suite-3.2.0.RELEASE-e4.2.2-win32.zip' from STS website. After extracting I could see 'sts-3.2.0.RELEASE' folder. I want to use this plugin in my existing Eclipse Kepler. After putting it in Eclispe Kepler's dropins/plugins folder I could not see the STS anywhere in Eclispe. Let me know what to do for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to get the Spring Tool Suite running on your machine. The first one is to download the full distribution for your platform, extract it, and run it as it is. It comes as a ready to use distribution that already includes Eclipse and a lot of additional plugins installed. That seems to be the bit that you downloaded. Although I would recommend to use the latest version (STS 3.6.1 on Eclipse 4.4) in that case.

The second way is to install the STS components into an existing Eclipse installation. You can do that by using the Eclipse Marketplace menu in your existing Eclipse installation. Browse for the matching STS version in there (the one that matches your Eclipse version) and install it from there.

Please keep in mind that installing the STS components into an existing Eclipse installation doesn't automatically gives you all the third-party plugins that we bundle with the STS distribution, like the latest Maven integration for Eclipse, the m2e-wtp add-on, the AJDT m2e connector, etc. In case you would like to use them, you would have to install them yourself - or use the STS distribution itself.

I would not recommend to manually install plugins into directories yourself. It usually causes trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to add some points in Martin answer that after installing STS how can you begin with it in eclipse. For that click on Window -->Perspective --> Open Perspective -->Other

[image]

Now you will find option of Spring in the list. Select it.

[image]

Finally you can use STS in your eclipse to make a spring project.